# Importing multiple functions from python

Tags: python-3.x, import, coding-style

I want to import two functions from a module but the names are quite long so want to import them as abbreviations.

I am trying something like this:
`from module import function1, function2 as fn1, fn2`

However this gives an error *Cannot import name 'fn2' from module*

Comment: So `from module import function1 as fn1, function2 as fn2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct way:

```
from module import function1 as fn1, function2 as fn2
```